# I can't enqueue css using a function in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

My stylesheet is enqueued if i use

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/style.css">
```

but it's not included when i use

```
function include_css(){

    wp_enqueue_style('main_css',get_stylesheet_uri());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','include_css');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may correct the code like this :

```
function include_css(){

    wp_enqueue_style('main_css',get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','include_css');
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to enqueue the css file without specifying it's complete url the code you use i.e

```
> wp_enqueue_style('main_css',get_stylesheet_uri());
```

This means that you are adding the style.css file which is always on the root directory but still you are giving name as main_css first make sure which css you want to add then someone will able to properly answer your question and the css you are trying to add is in which directory.

Please refer to this link [get_stylesheet_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/)

Answer (score 0):

To enqueue a stylesheet use this in functions.php

```
1.we need to register our stylesheet.
2.we should enqueue it.
3.Hook to an action 
4.call the function where you want to enqueue it.

function include_css()
{
    wp_register_style('main_css',get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('main_css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','include_css');
```

call,
`<?php wp_head();?>`
in the place you want to enqueue it.(mostly in header.)

Answer (score -1):

Please add this code in theme's functions.php

function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array());
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );

Comment: please add more explanation